# How to prevent the insertion of rows/columns in Handsontable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable (http://handsontable.com/).
I want to keep the ability to drag the corner of a cell as I have it but I don't want the user to drag that past the table itself, thus creating more rows and/or cells.

How do I achieve this?

I've tried the following but it doesn't do anything:

```
allowInsertRow: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `maxRows` and `maxCols` to have the respective maximum number of rows and columns you already pre-defined. That way, the user cannot add new rows or columns.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        maxRows: 2,
        maxCols: 4
    });
```

Also, pay attention not to include `minSpareRows` option and hide the context menu.